# How can I peek at the next character in a file in Python 3?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, seek, peek

Suppose I'm building a parser, and I want to lookahead in the stream.

In Python 2, I could write:

```
def peek():
    next = inputfile.read(1)
    inputfile.seek(-1,1)
    return next
```

however, in Python 3, relative seeks were disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, you can use `inputfile.peek(1)[:1]`.

Comment: This does not work for me with the error "AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'peek'"

Comment: This assumes the file was opened in binary mode. (@winni2k that is the reason for your error.)

Answer (score 3):

This does not work in text mode, but it does work in binary mode:

```
>>> open('test', 'rb').peek(1)
b'test\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file.read(1)
file.seek(file.tell()-1)
```